# Superimpose objects on a video stream using Python and POVRAY

Tags: python, povray

I am using Vapory which is a wrapper Python library for Povray. It allows using Python functions to manipulate typical Povray operations.

I want to superimpose 3D models in every frame of my video stream. The way to do this in Vapory is the following:

```
from vapory import *
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_writer import ffmpeg_write_image

light = LightSource([10, 15, -20], [1.3, 1.3, 1.3])
wall = Plane([0, 0, 1], 20, Texture(Pigment('color', [1, 1, 1])))
ground = Plane( [0, 1, 0], 0,
                Texture( Pigment( 'color', [1, 1, 1]),
                         Finish( 'phong', 0.1,
                                 'reflection',0.4,
                                 'metallic', 0.3)))
sphere1 = Sphere([-4, 2, 2], 2.0, Pigment('color', [0, 0, 1]),
                                           Finish('phong', 0.8,
                                                  'reflection', 0.5))
sphere2 =Sphere([4, 1, 0], 1.0, Texture('T_Ruby_Glass'),
                Interior('ior',2))

scene = Scene( Camera("location", [0, 5, -10], "look_at", [1, 3, 0]),
               objects = [ ground, wall, sphere1, sphere2, light],
               included=["glass.inc"] )


def embed_in_scene(image):

    ffmpeg_write_image("__temp__.png", image)
    image_ratio = 1.0*image.shape[1]/image.shape[0]
    screen = Box([0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], Texture(
                    Pigment( ImageMap('png', '"__temp__.png"', 'once')),
                    Finish('ambient', 1.2) ),
                 'scale', [10, 10/image_ratio,1],
                 'rotate', [0, 20, 0],
                 'translate', [-3, 1, 3])
    new_scene = scene.add_objects([screen])
    return new_scene.render(width=800, height=480, antialiasing=0.001)

clip = (VideoFileClip("bunny.mp4") # File containing the original video
        .subclip(23, 47) # cut between t=23 and 47 seconds
        .fl_image(embed_in_scene)  # <= The magic happens
        .fadein(1).fadeout(1)
        .audio_fadein(1).audio_fadeout(1))
clip.write_videofile("bunny2.mp4",bitrate='8000k')
```

which [results with a video stream](https://youtu.be/M9R21SquDSk) as follows:

[image]

What I want, however, is that movie box being the whole scene, and spheres to remain where they are. The first thought was to remove the rotation function from the code and it did work, however I still cannot stretch the movie frame to the end corners of the actual scene.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** So I was able to move the camera, get the object to the center. However I still could not get the movie full screen. This is because the camera object is told to look towards the coordinates, and I don't know what coordinates the camera should be directed at, in order to get the picture in full screen. See:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What do you mean by having the movie box being the whole scene? That the video-rectangle should be the same size as the background wall? Or that it takes the entire "screen" so that it's seen in 100% size and without skewed perspective independent of camera position/angle?

Comment: That the video should be the background entirely.